# for some input in python3 in increasing order of list not come right

Tags: python-3.x, input

my code is:

```
n=int(input())
list_1 = []
for i in range(n):
    list_1.append(input())
list_2=[]

#print(list_1)    
while list_1:
    minimum = list_1[0] 
    for x in list_1: 
        if x < minimum:
            minimum = x
    list_2.append(minimum)
    list_1.remove(minimum)
print (' '.join(map(str, list_2)))
```

all output come correct but incorrect come in some input like

```
4
10
3
7
6
```

please help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you perhaps clarify what it is that you're asking? It's not clearly stated what the problem is, and what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list 'list_1' is a list of strings, and for strings minimums work in a different manner. For example, '10' < '3' is True.

Change the line:

```
list_1.append(input())
```

To:

```
list_1.append(int(input()))
```

Comment: You are welcome!!! Kindly take out a moment from your schedule and upvote my answer and mark it as an acceptable solution. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do when posting questions here is properly explain your problem, and what the code does.

Now for your question, Mono found the issue in your code, but you should know that you do not need all this to sort a list of numbers.  It already exists in the language.  Use the `sort()` function on the list, like this:

```
print("This script will ask you for numbers and print them back to you in order.")

print("Enter how many numbers you will input: ", end="")
n=int(input())

list_1 = []

print("Please type each number.")
for i in range(n):
    print("   Number", i, ": ", end='')
    list_1.append(int(input()))

list_1.sort()
print("These are your numbers, in order:")
print (' '.join(map(str, list_1)))
```

The output is:

This script will ask you for numbers and print them back to you in order.
Enter how many numbers you will input: **4**
Please type each number.
   Number 0 : **10**
   Number 1 : **2**
   Number 2 : **8**
   Number 3 : **3**
These are your numbers, in order:
2 3 8 10